# Event Handling in BB10

Tags: qml, blackberry-10

I am developing a BB10 app that contains a login screen asking for Username and Password of the user. After that user presses the submit button.

I have designed the UI using QML

I want to capture the information given by the user (Username and password) and send it to a web service for verification.

I want to capture the information in a C++ class.

Can anyone suggest how can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### To answer the first part of your question:
 *"I want to capture the information given by the user"*

In your qml

```
Button {
    text: "Login"
    onClicked: {
        myQMLObj.login(userTextField.text,passTextField.text);
    }
}
```

In your namehere.hpp

```
public:
      // "Q_INVOKABLE" allows this function to be called from qml
      Q_INVOKABLE void login(QString user,QString pass);
```

In your namehere.cpp

```
namehere::namehere(bb::cascades::Application *app)
: QObject(app)
{
    QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///main.qml").parent(this);

    // expose C++ object in QML as an variable (so you can fire your login function
    qml->setContextProperty("myQMLObj", this);

    AbstractPane *root = qml->createRootObject<AbstractPane>();
    app->setScene(root);
}

void namehere::login(QString user, QString pass) {
    // Handle the user name & pass here
}
```

Hope that helps you atleast capture the data from the user. 
[After that you can begin to send it to a web service](http://www.makina-corpus.org/blog/access-json-webservice-qt-c)

[Just found this example, which explains alot better then me :)](http://bbcascadescode.tumblr.com/post/29294239402/running-c-function-from-qml-trivial-example)

Comment: thanks for the link...it seems very useful to me...I will try it and let you now it it works for me or not. :)

Comment: what is `myQMLObj` in `myQMLObj.login()` ? and don't we need to use `oncliked:` for calling the function ?

Comment: My bad! just fixed the button now! myQMLObj, is a varible that exposes your C++ so you can fire C++ functions from your QML

Comment: So this variable `myQMLObj` is by default available or we have to create it somewhere ?

Comment: oh I missed this part `qml->setContextProperty("myQMLObj", this);`. Now I understood from where it is coming. thanks a lot

Comment: No worries, it will probably be best to start a new question for your webservices problem (as it will need its own answer) :)

Answer (score 0):

First write a class that include QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkReply and maybe JsonDataAccess

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <bb/data/JsonDataAccess>
#include <bb/system/SystemToast>

using namespace bb::data;
using namespace bb::system;

class Member : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Member();
    virtual ~Member();

    Q_INVOKABLE void login(QString username, QString password);

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager;
    QString username;
    QString password;

signals:
    void serverReply();

private slots:
    void replyFinished(QNetworkReply*);
};
```

Then, load the class into QML

```
qmlRegisterType<Member>("com.library", 1, 0, "Member");
```

Import the library package into QML by adding

```
import com.library 1.0
```

Then initialize the member class at attachedObjects at QML. You can call login method as it is in Q_INVOKABLE form. Hope this help.